# Getting Error as htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, email, laravel-5

```
$email_ids=  DB::table('users')->pluck('email_id');
$name  = DB::table('users')-> pluck('name');

foreach ($email_ids as $email_id ) {                
   Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $name ] , function ($message) use ($email_id) {
        $message->from('abc@xyz.com', 'ABC');
        $message->to($email_id)->subject("Welcome");
   });    
}
```

I want to send a mail to respective users with their names in email. I get `$email_ids` and `$name` in array. but when I run this code , I get error as

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

When I replace `'user' => $name` with `'user' => $email_id` . I runs successfully.

When I send mail it should be like

```
Hello , $name(name of user)
```

Thank You

Comment: What is the value of `$name`, can you do `print_r($name)` or `var_dump($name)`.  You will see that it is not a string as per the error message.

Comment: $name is an array. You cannot pass an array.

Comment: ymas... ["ABC ","XYZ","PQR"] . I get these values... Ravi Hirani... then what is the other way I can do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:-

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get(); // get all users
foreach ($users as $user ) { 
   $name =  $user->name; // get user's name
   $email_id =  $user->email_id; // get user's email
   Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $name ] , function ($message) use ($email_id) {
        $message->from('abc@xyz.com', 'ABC');
        $message->to($email_id)->subject("Welcome");
   });    
}
```

**Note**:- You can get specific columns from DB table via below query,

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email_id')->get();
```

Comment: It gives an error as `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: How can I get to know that if a link is opened from Computer or from Mobile device? I have used MobileESP but not getting it.

Comment: Thank you.. I ll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Laravel shows htmlentities() error when there is an error in view file.

In your case you are getting name and email in different-different arrays but you only foreach `$email_ids` not `$name` In this line

```
Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $name ] , function ($message) use ($email_id) {
```

in this `$name` is array of names return by query and you are printing it as string that's why it is giving that error.

To achieve what you want change your code like this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name')->addSelect('email_id')->get()->toArray();

foreach ($users _ids as $user ) {                
   Mail::send('mail', ['user' => $user->name ] , function ($message) use ($user->email_id) {
        $message->from('abc@xyz.com', 'ABC');
        $message->to($user->email_id)->subject("Welcome");
   });    
}
```